# Не получается получить координаты с GPS

Tags: android, gps, координаты

Почему у меня "вылетает" приложение, когда я пытаюсь получить координаты с GPS. Если что в коде я пометил комментарием где ошибка вылетает, во время запуска.

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) this);
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);// Вот тут приложение вылетает !!!
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public class coordinats{
        public double Latitude;
        public double Longitude;
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        if (location != null)
        {
            coordinats position = new coordinats();
            position.Latitude = location.getLatitude();
            position.Longitude = location.getLongitude();
            new Gson().toJson(position);

        }
    }

    public void conect (View v){
        Thread network = new Thread(new ClientThread());
        network.start();
    }

    private Socket socket;

    private static final int SERVERPORT = 1111;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "1.23.45.67";

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.813, 144.962);
        Marker melbourne = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(MELBOURNE)
                .title("Melbourne")
                .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.fingerbig)));
```

--- **UPD** ---

```
05-10 16:28:54.579 3967-3974/myhome.gps_tracker I/art: Debugger is active
05-10 16:28:54.590 3967-3967/myhome.gps_tracker I/System.out: Debugger has connected
05-10 16:28:54.590 3967-3967/myhome.gps_tracker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-10 16:28:54.800 3967-3967/myhome.gps_tracker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-10 16:28:55.010 3967-3967/myhome.gps_tracker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-10 16:28:55.220 3967-3967/myhome.gps_tracker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-10 16:28:55.429 3967-3967/myhome.gps_tracker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-10 16:28:55.640 3967-3967/myhome.gps_tracker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-10 16:28:55.849 3967-3967/myhome.gps_tracker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-10 16:28:56.059 3967-3967/myhome.gps_tracker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-10 16:28:56.269 3967-3967/myhome.gps_tracker I/System.out: debugger has settled (1431)
05-10 16:28:56.283 3967-3967/myhome.gps_tracker W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/myhome.gps_tracker-1/lib/x86
05-10 16:28:56.379 3967-3967/myhome.gps_tracker W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/myhome.gps_tracker-1/lib/x86
05-10 16:28:56.536 3967-4022/myhome.gps_tracker I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
05-10 16:28:56.547 3967-4022/myhome.gps_tracker E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
05-10 16:28:56.547 3967-4022/myhome.gps_tracker E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
05-10 16:28:56.551 3967-3967/myhome.gps_tracker D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-10 16:28:56.551 3967-3967/myhome.gps_tracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: myhome.gps_tracker, PID: 3967
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{myhome.gps_tracker/myhome.gps_tracker.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<myhome.gps_tracker.MainActivity> cannot be instantiated
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<myhome.gps_tracker.MainActivity> cannot be instantiated
                                                                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Пермишн `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` добавили в манифест?

Comment: Да, конечно добавил

Comment: Тогда без стэктрейса тяжело гадать

Comment: Что за ошибка-то в логе?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja тему обновил

Comment: @qwerty123 тему обновил

Answer (score 2):

`MainActivity` обьявлена как `abstract`, а вы прописали ее в манифесте и система не может создать ее экземпляр.
Вот и вся разгадка, GPS совсем ни при чем.

Comment: То есть мне надо убрать "abstract"

Comment: Я не вижу всего кода класса, поэтому не могу судить можно ли просто убрать `abstract`. Почитайте что-нить про наследование в Java и абстрактные классы\методы, сможете на этот вопрос ответить самостоятельно.